# how to display matching values from different tables which used in joins without duplicates

Tags: mysql, join

Here, I wrote a query using joins, the relation is fine, but I wanted display multiple columns from different tables which I used in joins, when I am trying to include or select other table columns it is performing cross join. Getting confused how to do add those columns which matches the conditions in joins. Can anyone please help me on this

```
select distinct p.*,ps.*,pp.*,pd.VERIFICATION_SUBJECT_ID,pd.VALUE
from Players p 
join Players_Service ps on p.ID=ps.ID
join Players_Data pd on pd.VERIFICATION_SUBJECT_ID=ps.VERIFICATION_SUBJECT_ID
join Players_Property pp on pp.ID=ps.ID
```

Players table:

```
[{ID:1,NAME:'abc'}]
```

Players_Data table:

```
[{VERIFICATION_SUBJECT_ID:3, VALUE:'AB-TYS'},{VERIFICATION_SUBJECT_ID:4, VALUE:'AB-QE'}]
```

Players_Property:

```
[{ID:1,CITY:'XYZ',ID:2,CITY:'ABC'}]
```

Player_Service:

```
[{VERIFICATION_SUBJECT_ID:3,PLACE:'ABCDE'}]
```

Expected Output:

```
ID:1,
NAME:'abc',
VERIFICATION_SUBJECT_ID:3,
PLACE:'ABCDE',
CITY:'XYZ',
VALUE:'AB-TYS'
```

Comment: I wanted to select the all columns for one table, and 2 specified columns from another table, when I am trying to do that in data I am able to see repetative. I have to display the columns of different tables based on matching values in condition

Comment: Added sample records and expected result

Comment: No for understanding of data I have added in the form of json

Comment: Yes, There is no relation between players, players_data and there is no another table to connect these tables. But I want to display players_data columns and players_property columns in result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using ".*", spell out the columns you desire:

```
SELECT p.ID,
       p.NAME,
       pd.VERIFICATION_SUBJECT_ID,
       ...
```